# Use a host-variable to supply "IN" condition to a static SQL statement in Pro*C?

Tags: sql, c, oracle-pro-c

I have two tables as below:

**User table:**

```
UserID | Name  | Age      | Address  | Tel      | Company
----------------------------------------------------------
  1    | John  | 20       | CA       | 23467    | CompanyA
  2    | Peter | 41       | DE       | 17423    | CompanyB
  3    | Marry | 37       | TH       | 74244    | CompanyC
```

**Area table:**

```
Area   | Status
---------------
10001  | No
10002  | No
10003  | No
```

I use the last three fields of User table as the condition (3 conditions at the same time) to update Status of Area table (No -> Yes). Using memcpy for each variable:

```
WHERE (Address, Tel, Company) IN ( (:variable1, :variable2, :variable3) )
```

It returns error 1408. Any idea? 
Besides, is it possible to use only one host-variable and pass a string like this "'CA','2347','CompanyA'"?

Comment: ORA-01408 is to do with index creation. Querying the users gable with that form of `where` clause works fine, though it would be more normal to use three separate equality checks (`address = :variable1 and ...`. What is the whole statement you're running to get that error - or whatever error you're really getting? And what is the connection between the two tables?

Answer (score 1):

I did not know you can write a WHERE clause like this. I think it should be:

```
WHERE Address IN :var1 AND Tel IN :var2 AND Company in :var3;
```

Comment: While this is more a more normal pattern, what the OP shows does work.